# wildfly as systemd service

Tags: java, wildfly-8, systemd

I wanna make wildfly-domain as a systemd service in centos7
in works by root user but when i start it as `wilfly` user after a while it shows error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native threadESC
>
> and stop . even stop service doesn't work .

I tried to change heap-memo and ... but the user is a problem!
How can I solve this?

service file is ib wildfly8/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-redhat.sh
I tried "ulimit -n " at the top of service script but nothing changed!
I have 256Gb Ram and 64core CPU but ....

Comment: Include the `systemd` `.service` file you are having a problem with in your question

Comment: what do you mean ? what should i add in where ?

Comment: You said you are using `systemd` service. So, there should be a file with the extension `.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`. If you aren't using a `.service` file, you aren't using `systemd`. If you are *are*, paste the contents of that `.service` file into your question.

Comment: i did it in /etc/init.d/ but i changed it into systemd .now i have a systemd wilfly service . when i run it by root user , no problem but when i start it with wilfly user i works , but after 5 minutes it fall down as i said , how can i change wilfly user limitations ?

Comment: You are using a 64bit JDK aren't you ?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/

Comment: i use openJDK 1.5.0.121 . i told you if run domain.sh with root user every things are ok . but wildfly user after a while shutdown the application

Answer (score 14):

Right place for unit is:

```
/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service
```

This minimal is ok

```
[Unit]
Description=WildFly application server
Wants=network-online.target 
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=web
Group=web
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/domain.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=20

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should edit only ExecStart field to match your path.

Create user **web** with

```
useradd web
```

Also exec by root:

```
chown -R web:web /opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/
```

When

```
systemctl start wildfly
systemctl enable wildfly
```

If you get OOMs, inspect your limits

**[Service]** section of systemd unit, like

```
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitNOFILE=64000
LimitNPROC=64000
```

or 
    /etc/security/limits.d/
    /etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: `network.target` might be too early (had problem with that on fast machine with RHEL7); use `Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target` so that the interfaces are properly configured on OS side; taken from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started/126146#126146

Comment: For network servers it shouldn't matter, but I guess, it will not harm anyway. So, edited my post, thanks.